# Auto scroll images on page load, stop on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

JS newbie here. I have an issue that is probably has a fairly simple answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I wasn't sure exactly what to call this thing.

I have text in a div and when you hover over it, it displays a picture in another div. This is working fine, but I would like to have it scroll through the images automatically when the page loads. Once the user hovers over one of the text divs, I'd like the auto scroll to stop.

I have a Codepen of how I have it set up here: https://codepen.io/johnballman/pen/dwEwRz

HTML:

```
<div class="app-screen">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div id="features">
 <article data-src="http://placehold.it/350x150">Link 1</article>
  <article data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250">Link 2</article>
  <article data-src="http://placehold.it/350x350">Link 3</article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.app-screen {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

img.active{
    z-index: 2 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
  transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#features article").hover( function() {
    var value=$(this).attr('data-src');
    $(".app-screen img").attr("src", value);
});
$(this).switchClass("", "active", 1000);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *"the auto scroll"* you could be a bit more specific. There's a dozen ways to interpret that *scroll thing*.

Comment: I want them to cycle through. Show the first image then after a second or two show the second image, then show the third image. Then repeat. I didn't know the right terminology, which is probably why I couldn't find an answer when I searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `setInterval` to loop a `c` *current counter*.
- Use `++c % tot` (where tot is the number of links) to: increment-loop the counter.
- Use only Classes. That way you can have multiple `.Features` elements in a single page!
- Create `show`, `stop` and `play` functions. `show` is to show a `c` image; `stop` is to stop the interval, and `play` to start your magic.

```js
/**
 * Features
 * Auto-change articles featured images
 */

$('.Features').each((i, el) => {

  const $this  = $(el);
  const $image = $this.find('.Features-image');
  const $link  = $this.find('.Features-link');
  const tot    = $link.length;
  let c = 0;      // Counter to keep track of Current image
  let itv = null; // Interval loop
  
  const show = () => {
    $image.css({backgroundImage: `url("${$link.eq(c).data().src}")`});
    $link.removeClass('is-active').eq(c).addClass('is-active');
  }
  const stop = () => clearInterval(itv);
  const play = () => itv = setInterval(() => {
      c = ++c % tot; // Preincrement + loop (% = reminder operator)
      show();        // Show c image
    }, 3000);
    
  // Link mouseenter 
  $link.on({
    mouseenter() {
      c = $link.index(this);
      stop(); // Stop ongoing auto-play
      show(); // Show c image 
    },
    mouseleave() {
      play(); // Play on mouseleave
    }
  });
  
  // Init
  show(); // Show c image
  play(); // Start play!

});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

/**
 * Features
 * jQuery-handled articles with featured images
 */

.Features {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.Features-image {
  background: #aaa  50% / cover no-repeat none;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  flex: 0 1 40%;
}

.Features-links {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.Features-link {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.Features-link:hover,
.Features-link.is-active{
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="Features">
  <div class="Features-image"></div>
  <div class="Features-links">
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/0bf">Link 1</article>
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/f0b">Link 2</article>
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/0fb">Link 3</article>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Features">
  <div class="Features-image"></div>
  <div class="Features-links">
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/28a">Lorem</article>
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/a28">Ipsum</article>
    <article class="Features-link" data-src="//placehold.it/350x350/8a2">Dolor</article>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```